# What is the meaning of k-th largest absolute value?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a matrix. What is the meaning of $λ_k$ is the eigenvalue with $k$-th largest absolute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the eigen decomposition, you can order the eigenvalues. The k-th largest eigenvalue is $\lambda_k$, which is usually the k-th most important eigenvalue of the decomposed matrix.